# Invert checkbox on submit: Set HTML form value only if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, prototypejs

I need to "invert" a checkbox, i.e. submit the value if the checkbox is unchecked, and leave it empty if the checkbox is checked.

**I do not want to prevent form submission!**

I can think of two approaches:

1. change appearance of the checkbox so that it looks checked if it actually isn't and vice versa
2. change a hidden input via JavaScript when the checkbox is clicked

What's the best way to approach this? I would prefer a "pure" general solution, but since I need it for a project with [twitter-bootstrap-3](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) and [prototypejs](/questions/tagged/prototypejs), I tagged the question accordingly and if there is an easy way using these frameworks, that's great too.

### This works as intended:

```
<form id="the_form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="checkbox" id="the_checkbox" name="the_checkbox" value="foo" />
</form>
<script>
    document.forms.the_form.observe('submit', function() {
        document.getElementById('the_checkbox').checked = ! document.getElementById('the_checkbox').checked;
    });
</script>
```

But you will see the checkbox status changing before the next page has loaded.

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: I added an example that does what I need but with not-so-good UX, to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so what i've understood is that you want to inverse the checkbox.

If it's checked dont send value with the form.

If unchecked then send the value with the form.

I only didn't get if you want to submit the form on checkbox click.

Make a hidden input with the same name that has the value.
When the checkbox is checked then disable the hiddenbox.

```
<input type='hidden' id='hiddenCheckboxValue' value='something' name='testbox'>
<input type='checkbox' value='' name='testbox'>


$('#my_checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        document.getElementById('hiddenCheckboxValue').disabled = true;
    } else {
       document.getElementById('hiddenCheckboxValue').disabled = false;
    }
    //If you want to submit on checkbox click
    $( "#form" ).submit();

});
```

//EDIT forgot that unchecked checkboxes dont get send. fixed i think

Comment: using `disabled` with a hidden input works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onsubmit` event this way:

```
$(".form-class").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$("#checkbox").is("checked"))
    $(this).submit();
  else
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I want to submit the *form* in any case, just not include this particular value (as if the checkbox had been unchecked)

Comment: @fschmengler How do you want it to post the data to the server when the checkbox is not checked?

Comment: With the value (as if the checkbox had been checked)

Comment: @fschmengler So is the checkbox a dummy one?

Comment: Technically I want the checkbox to work the opposite way as by default. I updated the question title, hope it is better understandable now.

Comment: @fschmengler That's what I did.

Comment: @fschmengler Have to checkboxes... Make them toggle each other... Use the hidden one for the submit button and active one for the user to see. So by that way, hidden becomes false, if the visible is checked.

Answer (score 1):

you can dynamically add/remove  elements to the form:

```
$('the_form').observe('submit', function(event){
  $$('#the_form input[type=checkbox]').each(function(input){
    if (! input.checked) $('the_form').insert({top: new Element('input', {
         type: 'hidden'
       , class: 'dynamicInsert'
       , name: input.name
       , value: 'off'
       })
     });
  });
  this.submit();
  $$('#the_form input.dynamicInsert').each(function(input){
    input.remove();
  });
  event.stop(); // don't know if .submit() accepts an event object as parameter
  return false;
});
```